# How to deal with a casino night-out

Tags: friends, social-event, friend-groups

My friends and I are planning to go on a casino night-out.

We are generally ok with gambling; we have no gambling addictions and we just have fun when we win and, why not, slightly make fun of ourselves when we lose.

We are Italian, and since casinos, except for one in Venice, are kind of illegal, we go to Swiss ones, which are basically acceptable and give us no problems.

I personally went to a casino before, and I must say that the habits of the customers are very different: some of them just play for fun, some of them play with friends and some of them are basically addicted to gaming.

The kind of customer that leaves me speechless is the one who blames the game on others and who basically thinks that "God" or any other higher power is against him. Although this type is very rude and annoying, I don't see the bodyguard doing anything.  To be clear... this was not a single person but 5 or 6 who behaved like this.

The last time I went to the casino it was only me, so it was easy to let them do their show and ignore them, but some of my friends are not so "polite" when they lose or someone blames them for what they do.

So, how to avoid these kinds of players? How to make it clear to the casino that we are not the problem (if some incident arises), but their lack of bodyguard efficiency?

Comment: assuming casinò doesn't really care on who is bad / good but on who pays more, i'm more interested on avoiding problems

Comment: Why do you say it's bad of the security not to act on people who are, basically, just poor losers? That doesn't seem to hurt anyone. Now, if your friends are going to cause a scene because someone blames them for losing, _they_ are going to be a problem that needs to be dealt with.

Comment: You seem to be one of those people who have the ability to "smell" trouble. Use it. If you feel the situation coming up one your friends (assuming you yourself are more evasive of confrontation) could be "aroused in anger" soon, suggest changing games or tables ... I don't know if approaching security staff early on with a complaint is a good idea without knowing the place, but it could be an option.

Comment: So you're trying to plan ahead for something that likely won't even be a problem? If you aren't that type of person, why do you think this is even something you need to prepare for? What do your two questions have to do with each other? I'm really not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: I think you need to be specific as to what these "poor sports" are doing and how your friends react, because I'm very confused as to what the issue is.

Answer (score 14):

Ignoring these people is the correct answer. They're just caught up in their game, or lack sportsmanship, or are having a bad day, or are drunk or whatever. Thing is, it doesn't hurt anyone if they shout out "NO! DAMN YOU [X]!". Even if they point at someone they are playing with. It's not *nice* but it's not *hurtful* either.

If they very specifically single out one person, and move towards them and start an argument with them or whatever, then you could tell security, but probably security would intervene on their own at that point. Or you could continue to ignore them until they go away.

Now, if your friends are going to make a huge issue out of the fact that someone is blaming them for losing a game, then *your friends* are the problem, and you should probably educate them about ignoring other folks in the casino. Because if they start the argument, or get involved in the argument, or otherwise start trouble, *they* will be removed, and rightly so.

Comment: _"you should probably educate them"_ While I agree with everything in this answer, I'd like to add that this specific part can be tricky. Dealing with "hot-tempered" friends can be pretty exhausting (to say the least). OP should probably have some "strategies" at hand a priori. Anon: Better think about who is coming? Who is likely to be the "trouble-maker" (or easily offended)? Who's got the shortest temper? And you should be aware that there *could* be a point where you better separate from the group. (Someone will have to bail them out, perhaps ;) )